# Express CANNOT POST after firebase function deployment

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, http-post

I can make this method to work in local but i get `CANNOT POST /` and `CANNOT GET /` after deploying to firebase. Body of the `POST` and `GET` method is the `ipify api` to get information about the requesting IP.

- My local node.js version is v16.13.1
- Firebase node.js version is v14
- My Firebase is on Blaze (Pay as you go) plan

Running and working fine in Local and tested with *POSTMAN* tool:

```
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //application/json
app.route('/post').post((requests, responses) => {
  request('https://api64.ipify.org/?format=json', { json: true }, (err, ipfyResponse, body) => {
    responses.send(`
    ipfyResponse.statusCode: ${ipfyResponse.statusCode}\n
    ipfyResponse.statusMessage: ${ipfyResponse.statusMessage}\n
    `);
    console.log(ipfyResponse.body);
    console.log(ipfyResponse.headers);
    console.log(requests.body);
    console.log(requests.headers);
  });
});
app.listen(8080, () => console.log(`Server at localhost:8080`));
```

The function that i am deploying and gives me CANNOT POST and CANNOT GET response:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const httprequest = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //application/json
app.post('/post', (requests, responses) => {
  httprequest('https://api64.ipify.org/?format=json', { json: true }, (err, ipfyResponse, body) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    responses.send(`
    ipfyResponse.statusCode: ${ipfyResponse.statusCode}\n
    ipfyResponse.statusMessage: ${ipfyResponse.statusMessage}\n
    `);
  });
  console.log(ipfyResponse.body);
  console.log(ipfyResponse.headers);
  console.log(requests.body);
  console.log(requests.headers);
});
exports.post = functions.https.onRequest(app);

app.get('/get', (requests, responses) => {
  httprequest('https://api64.ipify.org/?format=json', { json: true }, (err, ipfyResponse, body) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    responses.send(`
    ipfyResponse.statusCode: ${ipfyResponse.statusCode}\n
    ipfyResponse.statusMessage: ${ipfyResponse.statusMessage}\n
    `);
  });
  console.log(ipfyResponse.body);
  console.log(ipfyResponse.headers);
  console.log(requests.body);
  console.log(requests.headers);
});
exports.get = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Im testing my `POST` firebase function with:

```
curl -X POST -d key=value --ssl https://us-central1-somethinsomethin.cloudfunctions.net/post
```

And testing the `GET` firebase function with my web browser (Edge)

Comment: I am going to suggest multiple pointers to you : 1) You should definitely enable CORS using the `cors` express middleware and call these within these functions
cors(req, res, () =>  // ..});  2) You expose Express API as a single Cloud Function which will have multiple routes for POST,GET methods. You are currently creating two functions, one for get and other for post. Check this for [quickstarts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps)

Comment: 3) With Express app routing, the function name is added as a prefix to the URL paths in the app you define. For example, the URL to invoke the GET in the Express app example above looks like this:
https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/get/get  // where get is function name for GET method and get is the route

Comment: 4) Also request package has been deprecated as stated in the npm page [request-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Consider using other alternatives like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: Did you try the above suggestions I made? Please confirm if your issue is not resolved yet.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra I'm trying to make these changes, I will inform you of the result since I need this so bad.